# Failing to understand a rust generic function error

Tags: rust

I was trying to get a piece of Rust generic code to compile, and after mucking around for while narrowed it down to failure of this code to compile. I am not sure what exactly is breaking down here (E0308 doesn't help me much) -- I must be missing something silly:

```
fn is_fail<bool>() -> bool { false }
fn main(){
  let failure:bool = is_fail();
  //if ! failure {
    println!("{}", failure);
  //}
}
```

The error is:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
 --> <anon>:1:30
1 |> fn is_fail<bool>() -> bool { false }
  |>                              ^^^^^ expected type parameter, found bool
note: expected type `bool`
note:    found type `bool`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function the type parameter `bool` shadows the builtin type `bool`. So your function declaration is essentially the same as

```
fn is_fail<T>() -> T { false }
```

which clearly isn't well-typed.

Comment: Yes, but now it is clear why it is wrong. `false` is not of a generic type `T`.

Comment: Yes.. type "bool" is shadowed by type parameter "bool"!