# expected i32, found type parameter, but type parameter is i32

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Table<T> {
    table: Vec<Vec<T>>
}

impl<i32> Display for Table<i32>
    where i32: Display
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for (index, line) in self.table.iter().enumerate() {
            write!(f, "{}:\t", index+1);

            let mut sum = 0i32;
            for task in line {
                write!(f, "{} ", task);
                sum += *task;
            }

            write!(f, " : {}\n", sum);
        }

        Result::Ok(())
    }
}
```

This code results in a confusing error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/table.rs:48:24
   |
48 |                 sum += *task;
   |                        ^^^^^ expected i32, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `i32` (i32)
   = note:    found type `i32` (type parameter)
```

And I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have accidentally introduced a type parameter called `i32` (instead of, usually, `T`). I agree with you here, that the compiler diagnostic could be better.

Adding something after `impl` in angle brackets, likes this:

```
impl<i32> Display for Table<i32>
```

... will always introduce a new type parameter, just like e.g. `impl<T>`. To fix your problem, just remove this type parameter declaration from the `impl` keyword:

```
impl Display for Table<i32> { ... }
```

Note that I also removed the `where` bound which doesn't make sense anymore. You can't apply bounds to concrete types.

---

Related:

- [Expected type parameter, found u8, but the type parameter is u8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410672/rust-compiler-can-not-understand-same-types)
- [Failing to understand a rust generic function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320635/failing-to-understand-a-rust-generic-function-error)

Comment: It's works! Thanks!